# Cannot find module 'forwarded'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift, http-status-code-503

I'm trying to host my website on https://www.openshift.com/ . It's a website in node.js server side and angular.js client side. I used the node.js (Node.js 0.10) default application and added a MongoDB 2.4 cartridge.

Now when I run the web site, I'm having : `Service Temporarily Unavailable`.
I've connected to my application uning ssh, while running the following commands, here is what I have :

```
> cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
> node server.js -e production

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'forwarded'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/5456b331e0b8cd980200004a/app-root/
runtime/repo/node_modules/express/node_modules/proxy-addr/index.js:19:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Looks like a dependency issue, but I don't know how to solve this. The application runs properly in localhost.

**EDIT in response to Daniel:**

Here is what I have:

```
> cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR; npm install
npm WARN package.json express@4.9.8 No README data
npm WARN package.json mocha@1.21.4 No README data
npm WARN package.json passport-local-mongoose@0.3.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json passport@0.2.1 No README data
npm WARN package.json chai@1.9.1 No README data
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bcrypt-nodejs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bcrypt-nodejs
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/lib/openshift/5456b331e0b8cd980200004a/app-root/r
untime/repo/node_modules/express/node_modules/send requires on-finished@'2.1.0'
but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/lib/openshift/5456b331e0b8cd980200004a/app-root/r
untime/repo/node_modules/express/node_modules/on-finished,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this problem myself with a nextjs app.

### Possible Cause

I think the cause was I removed a package from the package.json file but didn't remove the package with `npm uninstall`/`yarn remove` so my lock file was still looking for it.

### Solution

In the end I deleted my `yarn.lock` file (if you're using yarn) and deleted my `node_modules` folder and then ran `yarn install` (`npm install`) and it all worked again

### Backup Solution

You could also rebuild any packages you suspect are giving you problems. Usually does the trick. Especially if you upgraded Node recently.

Comment: deleting package-lock.json just solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have install the dependencies on the server.

```
$ cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR; npm install
```